# How do I get timezone information on macOS with Java?

Tags: java, timezone, macos

How do I get timezone information on [*macOS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) (formerly known as *Mac OS X* and *OS X*), using Java?

Comment: Presumably the same way you do with Java on any other platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [TimeZone](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) class is used for time zones in Java. To get the system's default time zone, you can use the static `getDefault` method.

Comment: Now outdated. As of the adoption of JSR 310, the *java.time* classes supplanted the legacy date-time classes. Specifically, `TimeZone` is replaced by `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset` and `ZoneRules`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZoneId
.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) 
.getRules()
.isDaylightSavings​( 
    Instant.now() 
)
```

## *java.time*

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the terrible legacy date-time classes: `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset` and `ZoneRules`.

You asked:

> How do I get timezone information on Mac OS X, using Java?

Get time zone info through Java on a Mac the same way as on any other host OS.

### `ZoneId`

Define which time zone is of interest. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

### `ZoneRules`

Get the rules for that zone. Those rules include the history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of that particular region.

```
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
```

Interrogate for the rules in effect for any particular moment. Let's use the current moment for this demo.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment.
```

### `ZoneOffset`

Get the offset in use at this moment in that zone. An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind UTC (the prime meridian).

```
ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset( instant ) ;
```

### Daylight Saving Time (DST)

Ask if Daylight Saving Time (DST) is in effect at that moment in that zone.

```
boolean isDst = rules.isDaylightSavings​( instant ) ;
```

You can also ask for the previous and next transitions in that zone, and more.

### *tzdata*

Be aware that macOS has its own copy of the [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) data defining the time zones. Apple's OS updates include fresh copies. Be sure yours is up-to-date if a zone of interest to you is changing. This macOS copy affects most apps that are not Java-based.

A [Java Virtual Machine (JVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) includes its own *tzdata*. Again, if a time zone of interest to you is changing, be sure any and all JVMs in your usage are updated. Java updates include fresh *tzdata*. But politicians *really* like changing time zones, often with little or no forewarning. So you may need to manually update your JVM(s)’ *tzdata* file. And be sure to update any JVMs you have installed as well as any JVMs bundled with any Java-based apps you are using.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).